# Moving towards to bootstrap or fluid layout from Basic HTML & CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am not a web designer. I come from a statistics background and at the moment I am trying to simply put together a site. I have figured out the layout structure I want in the simply used `html` and plain `css` to get it started. After research around I see frameworks like bootstrap has really nice look and feel and want to move towards to that. My question is how can I build following structure in bootstrap.

HTML File

```
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="layout.css" media="screen" />
<div class="container">
    <div class="user_stats">
        User Statistics
    </div>
    <div class="hunt">
        suggestions
    </div>
    <div class="personal">
        personal
    </div>
</div>
</html>

.container {
    width:960px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

.user_stats, .personal, .hunt {
    background-color:#aaa;
    margin:0 0 5px 5px;
}
```

CSS File

```
.user_stats, .personal {
    width:400px;
    float:left;
}

.user_stats {
    height:200px;
}

.personal {
    height:300px;
}

.hunt {
    width:550px;
    height:505px;
    float:right;
}
```

Both personal and suggestions (in css personal and hunt) I want to add place holder for images and would like those boxes to have scroll bars.

Here is a screenshot of what it looks like with the code I have:
[image: how it looks like]

Comment: If you want to use bootstrap-3, which is responsive you would not use hard-coded pixel widths, but instead you would use percentages.  Bootstrap allows you to do this with a 12 column system.  Have you read bootstrap docs for more information on this? http://getbootstrap.com

Answer (score 0):

Basically the code for your layout would be like this

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="col-md-5">
   <div class="row">User Statistics</div>
   <div class="row">Personal</div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-7">
   Suggestions
 </div>
</div>
```

of course you will need to link to the bootstrap.css to get the grid classes.

For each of the divs to have scrollbars , use the below class on the desired divs

```
.scrolldiv {
height:550px;
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: auto;
}
```

i.e

```
<div class="col-md-5">
 <div class="row scrolldiv">User Statistics</div>
 <div class="row scrolldiv">Personal</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-7 scrolldiv">
 Suggestions
</div>
```